Pololu DRV8833 not working with pico
I am trying to use a Pololu DRV8833 driver to drive a DC motor via a pico.
Below is the setup

from machine import Pin
m1 = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
m2 = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
m1.high()
m2.low()

The red and black cable connect to a 6V power source and here is a link to the driver: https://thepihut.com/products/pololu-drv8833-dual-motor-driver-carrier
The issue is that the setup doesn't work and I cannot work out why. As far as I understand I need to apply a current via one pin and not have a current on the other. Am I missing something?

The pin headers on your DRV8833 board aren't soldered and therefore don't make good contact (if they make any contact at all). Solder them.
